# Magento - I have created two sliders in magento and two sliders sharing same jquery code 1st one is working and the second one is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, magento

Whn creating two sliders, the slider 1 is working properly where the second slider is not working at all..
both the sliders are sharing same jquery code for animation...
Please help me to get rid of that..

Comment: Use different function for each slider

Comment: try using same class name for both slider instead of id..